# Setting values with pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Having this DataFrame:

```
import pandas

dates = pandas.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=5, freq='H')
s = pandas.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], index=dates)
df = pandas.DataFrame([(1, 2, s, 8)], columns=['a', 'b', 'foo', 'bar'])
df.set_index(['a', 'b'], inplace=True)

df
```

[image]

I would like to replace the Series in there with a new one that is simply the old one, but resampled to a day period (i.e. `x.resample('D').sum().dropna()`).

When I try:

```
df['foo'][0] = df['foo'][0].resample('D').sum().dropna()
```

That seems to work well:

[image]

However, I get a warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

The question is, how should I do this instead?

### Notes

Things I have tried but do not work (resampling or not, the assignment raises an exception):

```
df.iloc[0].loc['foo'] = df.iloc[0].loc['foo']
df.loc[(1, 2), 'foo'] = df.loc[(1, 2), 'foo']
df.loc[df.index[0], 'foo'] = df.loc[df.index[0], 'foo']
```

A bit more information about the data (in case it is relevant):

- The real DataFrame has more columns in the multi-index. Not all of them necessarily integers, but more generally numerical and categorical. The index is unique (i.e.: there is only one row with a given index value).
- The real DataFrame has, of course, many more rows in it (thousands).
- There are not necessarily only two columns in the DataFrame and there may be more than 1 columns containing a Series type. Columns usually contain series, categorical data and numerical data as well. Any single column is always single-typed (either numerical, or categorical, or series).
- The series contained in each cell usually have a variable length (i.e.: two series/cells in the DataFrame do not, unless pure coincidence, have the same length, and will probably never have the same index anyway, as dates vary as well between series).

Using Python 3.5.1 and Pandas 0.18.1.

Comment: Setting a Series inside a cell of a Dataframe makes me think you may want to use a pandas Panel. I'm no good with Panels myself, so I'll just leave this link here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html

Comment: Can you provide a little more definition of you data?  with `foo` always be a series? Will `bar` always be one number?  Could you provide more *rows*?

Comment: @tmthydvnprt: I just updated my question with a bit more information about the data (see the "Notes" section). :-)

Comment: I am still a little unclear the how it looks, could you make an example `df` with some of these corner cases?

Comment: @tmthydvnprt: I don't think it is worthy. Although I appreciate your help, I cannot really change the way data looks like (it is not up to me to decide how those DataFrames are created/stored). And I think your answer goes in that way. :-) So, I think my problem can really be simplified as posted in the question (that is the exact problem and how it can be reproduced, the rest does not really matter).

Comment: In pandas I rearrange data all the time (from how it was given to me) to best fit my needs and the features of the library.  But I understand if you cannot.  I would respectfully still argue you should as I think it will may your life easier... but only you would know. See my update about variable length Series in a few moments. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('foo')] = df['foo'][0].resample('D').sum().dropna()
```

Pandas is complaining about chained indexing but when you don't do it that way it's facing problems assigning whole series to a cell. With [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) you can force something like that. I don't think it would be a preferable thing to do, but seems like a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set `df.is_copy = False` before asignment of new value.

Answer (score 0):

## Hierarchical data in pandas

It really seems like you should consider restructure your data to take advantage of pandas features such as [`MultiIndexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) and [`DateTimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).  This will allow you to still [operate on a index in the typical way](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling) while being able to [select on multiple columns across the hierarchical data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) (`a`,`b`, and`bar`).

### Restructured Data

```
import pandas as pd

# Define Index
dates = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=5, freq='H')
# Define Series
s = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], index=dates)

# Place Series in Hierarchical DataFrame
heirIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([1,2,8], names=['a','b', 'bar'])
df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=heirIndex)

print df
```

---

```
a                    1
b                    2
bar                  8
2016-01-01 00:00:00  0
2016-01-01 01:00:00  1
2016-01-01 02:00:00  2
2016-01-01 03:00:00  3
2016-01-01 04:00:00  4
```

### Resampling

With the data in this format, resampling becomes very simple.

```
# Simple Direct Resampling
df_resampled = df.resample('D').sum().dropna()

print df_resampled
```

---

```
a            1
b            2
bar          8
2016-01-01  10
```

## Update (from data description)

If the data has variable length `Series` each with a different `index` and non-numeric categories that is ok.  Let's make an example:

```
# Define Series
dates = pandas.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=5, freq='H')
s = pandas.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], index=dates)

# Define Series
dates2 = pandas.date_range('2016-01-14', periods=6, freq='H')
s2 = pandas.Series([-200, 10, 24, 30, 40,100], index=dates2)
# Define DataFrames
df1 = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([1,2,8,'cat1'], names=['a','b', 'bar','c']))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(s2, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([2,5,5,'cat3'], names=['a','b', 'bar','c']))

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print df
```

---

```
a                      1      2
b                      2      5
bar                    8      5
c                   cat1   cat3
2016-01-01 00:00:00  0.0    NaN
2016-01-01 01:00:00  1.0    NaN
2016-01-01 02:00:00  2.0    NaN
2016-01-01 03:00:00  3.0    NaN
2016-01-01 04:00:00  4.0    NaN
2016-01-14 00:00:00  NaN -200.0
2016-01-14 01:00:00  NaN   10.0
2016-01-14 02:00:00  NaN   24.0
2016-01-14 03:00:00  NaN   30.0
2016-01-14 04:00:00  NaN   40.0
2016-01-14 05:00:00  NaN  100.0
```

The only issues is that after resampling. You will want to use [`how='all'`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html?highlight=how) while dropping `na` rows like this:

```
# Simple Direct Resampling
df_resampled = df.resample('D').sum().dropna(how='all')

print df_resampled
```

---

```
a              1    2
b              2    5
bar            8    5
c           cat1 cat3
2016-01-01  10.0  NaN
2016-01-14   NaN  4.0
```

Comment: As you may have noticed after the update (sorry for not providing this information before), this may not be possible, as the series contained in the DataFrame have a variable length and different index (and yes, there are many series contained in the DataFrame).

Comment: You can have variable lengths and disparate indexes!  The DataFrame will just be `nan` where ever they do not overlap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :-)